# Simpliflying jQuery calls that use redundant data

Tags: jquery, function, redundancy

I have a bit of code that controls some `div`s but its repeats a lot just for one little change on a different link

If I click `#Option1` then 2-5 shrink to 0 (if any of them are open) and go to 0 opacity
and vice versa if you click 2 (collapsing 1 and the rest) but i cant think of a good way to make it more generic but there has to be a way

```
$('#Option1').click(function() {
      var ele = $('#Option1Div');
      ele.animate({
               opacity    : .75,
               width      : '602px'
          }, 5000, function() {
          // Animation complete.
  });
      var ele = $('#Option2Div');
      ele.animate({
               opacity    : 0.1,
               width      : '0px'
          }, 5000, function() {
          // Animation complete.
  });
      var ele = $('#Option3Div');
      ele.animate({
               opacity    : 0.1,
               width      : '0px'
          }, 5000, function() {
          // Animation complete.
  });
      var ele = $('#Option4Div');
      ele.animate({
               opacity    : 0.1,
               width      : '0px'
          }, 5000, function() {
          // Animation complete.
  });
      var ele = $('#Option5Div');
      ele.animate({
               opacity    : 0.1,
               width      : '0px'
          }, 5000, function() {
          // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
  $('#Option1 , #Option2 ,#Option3 , #Option4 , #Option5').click(function() {
    var ele = $('#' + this.id + 'Div');
    ele.animate({
        opacity: .75,
        width: '602px'
    }, 5000, function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });

    $('[id^="Option"][id$="Div"]').not(ele).animate({
        opacity: 0.1,
        width: '0px'
    }, 5000, function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });
});
```

Comment: that is elegant but can i go cleaner? since clicking on say Option 2 sets Option2Div opacity to .75 and width to 602 while reducing 1 (and 3-5) to 0

Comment: Try the code pasted above.. It handles all the click events for the 5 Options div

Comment: that's perfect. very efficient! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you give your options a class of `options` and your divs a class of `option-divs`, you can use something like this:

```
$('.options').click(function() {
    var element = $('.option-divs').eq($(this).index());

    element.stop().animate({
        opacity: .75,
        width: '602px'
    }, 5000).siblings().stop().animate({
        opacity: 0.1,
        width: '0px'
    }, 5000);
});​
```

Comment: all great ideas, but the first seems simplist but take a look maybe it can be made more efficient http://tokusatsu.lurkerlordx.com/prototype.html

Comment: @NekoLLX: The approach that you're using isn't very good. `id`s shouldn't be used like this.

Comment: Can you explain why? I mean nothing is redundent they are only used onced so isn't ID preferable to Classes, Especially when later on things like the content divs will have different content

Comment: I mean, if it works, there's nothing really wrong with it, but generic solutions allow you to add/remove HTML elements without having to rewrite the JavaScript.

Comment: Well that's certinly more effecient and i love efficient, maybe i'll give it a try, my only real consern is when i srat dynamilly changingthe content in specific areas liek the OptionDivs, Subsection1, and the Header

Comment: Just tried your class/sibmings code and clicking on any spine image causes all divs, the other spines, and the sub headings to collapse into nothing. All i want to colapse is the Option-divs that aren't the one for the active spine. (I also am trying to get the sub heading 2 links to change to red to read when a dive is activated, or to triger the activation if you click on them, vice the page source to see my current build)

Comment: Without seeing your HTML, there's nothing that I can do.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, as you have different values for opacity, width, and eventually duration of animation, you cannot do a job purely generic.

But you could isolate all changing data in array and apply a generic code like:

```
    var opacities = [0.75, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1];
    var widths = [602, 0, 0, 0, 0];
    var durations = [500, 500, 500, 500, 500];
    var callbacksComplete = [cb1, cb2, cb3, cb4, cb5];

    $('#Option1').click(function() {

        // Assume that 3 arrays have the same size !
        for(var i = 0 ; i < opacities.length ; i++)
        {
            $('#Option' + i + 'Div').animate({
                'opacity' : opacities[i],
                'width' : widths[i]
            }, durations[i], callbacksComplete[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't need it totally generic...just more efficent then 5 calls of 5 functions The Arry looks good too